# I try make two relations one to many between 2 Entities but get Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: „Invalid column name 'FirstTeamId'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I read about some similar problems but I tried everything. I want to make 2 one-to-many relationships between classes `Game` and `Team`. One `Team1` to many games, and one `Team2` to many games.

I found some advice but it does not work. I tried with attributes `[ForeignKey]` and `[InverseProperty]` but the migration did not pass.

Then I used Fluent API - the migrattion works, but when I try to use `GetAllGames` method in Swagger, I get an error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'FirstTeamId'.
> Invalid column name 'SecondTeamId'.

The database works in SQL Server Management Studio, it looks like a problem with Entity Framework.

I know was some similar problems but I tried it and I don't know what's next.

I use .NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 6.06

I will be grateful for any advice.

Github:
https://github.com/MisiekMikolaj/TyperLeagueProblem

This is my code:

```
public class Game : EntityBase
{
    public int? FirstTeamId { get; set; }
    public int? SecondTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team? FirstTeam { get; set; }
    public Team? SecondTeam { get; set; }
    public List<Bet> Bet { get; set; }
    public string? Result { get; set; }
}

public class Team : EntityBase
{
    public List<Game> FirstTeamGames { get; set; }
    public List<Game> SecondTeamGames { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TyperLeagueStorageContext : DbContext
{
    public TyperLeagueStorageContext(DbContextOptions<TyperLeagueStorageContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Game>? Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team>? Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bet>? Bets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne(x => x.FirstTeam)
            .WithMany(x => x.FirstTeamGames)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FirstTeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne(x => x.SecondTeam)
            .WithMany(x => x.SecondTeamGames)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.SecondTeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the migration? Is the column there when you view the table in sql studio? How does the migration file look? What query is EF trying to run?

Comment: @huancz Yes, i applayed migratiion and made Update-database. Columns FirstTeamId and SecondTeamId are in table in sql studio. EF try to GetAllGames. Error is when program is in handler and try Select(x => new Models Game) from gamerepositorey.GetAll().

Comment: I meant actual `SELECT ...` statement. Set `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command` log level to Information, it will start logging all SQL.

Comment: "Error is when program is in handler and try Select(x => new Models Game) from gamerepositorey.GetAll()." Could you share you code about select ? So that we can  reproduce your problem.

Comment: @huancz I hope i did what You asked for. I add a jpg with info from command window.

Comment: @QingGuo I add a screenshot with a select fragment and link to my repository.

Comment: Most of the data point to database not being up to date, the column just doesn't exist in your DB. Yet you claim you can see them in sql studio... Maybe you have two databases, and looking at the wrong one? Different connection string in runtime vs. design time? Update-Database will probably update design time db. At this point I can only guess. You can try to add automatic migration in your Program (`dbContext.Database.Migrate()`) as a workaround, but you really should figure out where your data are going.

Comment: @huancz I made migration and update-database before push it to github. It is strange that app is working now. After edit this post i closed VS. Now I cloned my repository from github and this works. In sql studio is warning but swagger works. Maybe You are right and i updated different DataBase but i changed columne name and the changes was in sql studio too. Anyway thank you very much for your support and good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your github project, and it works almost out of the box. I had to replace `.\\SQLEXPRESS` with `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`. In both places (`TyperLeagueStorageContextFactory` and `appsettings.json`). Update-Database works, query to /Games returns normal 200 OK response with empty array.

Without access to your complete environment, it's hard to say what did go wrong, easiest way out of this is probably to drop your database and start fresh.

(I think you are setting yourself up for lot of pain with some of the choices you made, but that's not the topic discussed here. Pain is how we learn and this looks like learning project.)

Comment: Yes You are right it works. I dont know why but i cloned te project from repository and it works now. In sql server is warning "invalid columne name" but app works in swagger. Thank you very much for your support and good advice.